# NFS based mount fails in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I'm using `Kubernetes - v1.24.7` on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and facing problem with the `NFS - Persistent Volume` mount. When i tried to deploy my Jenkins deployment file it always fails with below errors.

```
$ kubectl describe pod jenkins-6786789d5d-m26zw -n jenkins

Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    25m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned jenkins/jenkins-6786789d5d-m26zw to worker-3
  Warning  FailedMount  5m31s (x2 over 14m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-65npd data]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  3m17s (x8 over 23m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[data kube-api-access-65npd]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  3m6s (x19 over 25m)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-nfs" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1 192.168.72.136:/mnt/nfs/stg/jenkins /var/lib/kubelet/pods/853c44ed-bf2b-4e6a-b666-c1adab7f7f4b/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pv-nfs
Output: mount.nfs: mounting 192.168.72.136:/mnt/nfs/stg/jenkins failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

The below `External NFS` mount path provided by our IT-Storage Administrator.

```
192.168.72.136:/nfs-volume
```

The below packages have already been installed on master and nodes.

```
apt install nfs-common
apt install cifs-utils
apt install nfs-kernel-server
```

In my master and workers(Host Machine) i have added below in `/etc/fstab` and i could mount the nfs volume.

```
192.168.72.136:/nfs-volume /mnt/nfs/stg/  nfs  defaults 0 0
```

However still same problem persisting while Kubernetes application deployment, Also tried with below option in `/etc/fstab` but same result.

```
192.168.72.136:/nfs-volume /mnt/nfs/stg/  nfs  rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

My `pv` & `pvc` volume status.

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pv-nfs    100Gi      RWX            Retain           Bound    jenkins/pvc-nfs   nfs                     11s

$ kubectl get pvc -n jenkins
NAME      STATUS   VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc-nfs   Bound    pv-nfs   100Gi      RWX            nfs            17s
```

My `PersistentVolume` and `Deployment` yml as follows.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs
  labels:
    type: pv-nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  mountOptions: 
  - nfsvers=4.0
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.72.136
    path: "/mnt/nfs/stg/jenkins"
    readOnly: false
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 0 
        runAsUser: 0
      serviceAccountName: admin
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /var/jenkins_home         
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs
```

Directory `/mnt/nfs/stg/jenkins` existing in NFS. Please let me know what I'm missing here?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the storage IT administrator has exported NFS share: `/nfs-volume` from `192.168.72.136`, then in the `PersistentVolume` spec, the path should be `/nfs-volume`.

Comment: ok. I will change the `/mnt/nfs/stg/jenkins` to `/nfs-volume` in `PersistentVolume` file and try it out.